# How to handle this warning?Help me

Tags: php

This is the warning I get :

> Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /home/dweetcom/public_html/admin_kepuasan.php on line 30

<---line 30 --->

```
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
```

<---admin_kepuasan.php--->

```
<?php
require_once 'connection1.php';
?>
<html>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href='https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css'/>

<?php

$sql="SELECT * FROM borang_kepuasan";
$result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);

echo "<table id='example' class='display' cellspacing='1' width='100%'>";
echo "<thead>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>Soalan 1</td>";
echo "<td>Soalan 2</td>";
echo "<td>Soalan 3</td>";
echo "<td>Soalan 4</td>";
echo "<td>Soalan 5</td>";
echo "<td>Soalan 6</td>";
echo "<td>Soalan 7</td>";
echo "<td>      Nota / Testimoni       </td>";
echo "</tr>";
echo "</thead>";
echo "<tbody>";

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>$row[soalan1]</td>";
        echo "<td>$row[soalan2]</td>";
        echo "<td>$row[soalan3]</td>";
        echo "<td>$row[soalan4]</td>";
        echo "<td>$row[soalan5]</td>";
        echo "<td>$row[soalan6]</td>";
        echo "<td>$row[soalan7]</td>";
        echo "<td>$row[nota]</td>"; 
        echo "</tr>";
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}

echo "</tbody>";
echo "</table>";
 echo "<center>";
 echo "<table>";
 echo "<tr>";
 echo "<td>";
     echo "<button style=height:30px width:80px value=Kembali onClick=location.href='admin1.php'>";
     echo "Kembali";
     echo "</button>";
 echo "</td>";
 echo "<td>";
     echo "<button style=height:30px width:80px value=Log Out onClick=location.href='logout.php'>";
     echo "Log Out";
     echo "</a>";
     echo "</button>";
echo "</center>";
?>
</html>
<script src='//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js'></script>
<script>
$('#example').DataTable();
</script>
```

<---connection1.php--->

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "dweetcom";
$password = "***********";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password) ;
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

@mysqli_select_db("dweetcom_borang",$conn);
?>
```

<--- the warning in 153:--->

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO borang_kepuasan(soalan1, soalan2, soalan3, soalan4, soalan5, soalan6, soalan7 ,nota) VALUES
```

<---borang_kepuasan.php--->

```
<html><head>
<style>
html
{
font-family:Lucida Grande, sans-serif;
color: rgba(158,4,22,0.91);


}

.container
{
max-width:699px;
height:86%;
margin:0 auto;

}
header
{
width:100%;
background-image: url("pink1.jpg");

}



.content

{

    border: 0px solid;
    padding: 20px; 
    width: 680px;
    height: 168%; 
    background:#ffe6e6;
}

.last
{
margin-right:0;
}

textarea
{font-family:"Lucida Grande";
 }

.table{
    font-family: "Lucida Grande";

    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 150%;
}
.td1{background-color: #dddddd;
font-family: "Lucida Grande";
font-size:16px;
}


.table1 {
    font-family: "Lucida Grande";
    font-size:16px;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
}

td, th {
    border: 1px solid #dddddd;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #dddddd;
}


p{
     font-family: "Lucida Grande";
     color: rgba(158,4,22,0.91);

}

button {
    background-color: white;
    color: black;
    border: 3px solid #e7e7e7;
    border-radius: 20px;
    width:150px;
    height:5%;

}
.hr {
color: rgba(158,4,22,0.91);
}

textarea {
 font-family: "Lucida Grande";
    font-size:16px;
}   
    .footer
{ p:2%}
button:hover {background-color: #e7e7e7;}

@media(max-width: 400px) {
  .col, nav ul li {

    width:95%;
    clear:both;
  }

}
</style>
<br/><br/><center><img src="logo_Dweet (2).588.png" width="400" /></center>
</head>

<body background="pink1.jpg"><br/>

<?php
include("connection1.php");
if(isset($_POST['hantar']))
{
// print_r($_POST); exit;
  $soalan1 = $_POST['soalan1'];
  $soalan2 = $_POST['soalan2'];
  $soalan3 = $_POST['soalan3'];
  $soalan4 = $_POST['soalan4'];
  $soalan5 = $_POST['soalan5'];
  $soalan6 = $_POST['soalan6'];
  $soalan7 = $_POST['soalan7'];
  $nota = $_POST['nota'];


  if($soalan1==" "||$soalan2==" "||$soalan3==" "||$soalan4==" "||$soalan5==" "||$soalan6==" " || $soalan7==" "||$nota==" ")
  {  

     echo "<center>";
     echo "<font size=6 face=Lucida Grande>";
     echo "<b>HARAP MAAF!</b>"; 
     echo "<br/>";
     echo "Terdapat maklumat yang belum dilengkapkan.";
     echo "<br/>";
     echo "Sila lengkapkan maklumat anda.";
     echo "<br/>";
     echo "<br/>";
     echo "<button style=height:50px width:20px color:#000000; value=Kembali onClick=history.go(-1);return true;>";
     echo "Kembali";
     echo "</button>";
     echo "</font>";
     echo "</center>";
  }
  else
  {
     mysql_query("INSERT INTO borang_kepuasan(soalan1, soalan2, soalan3, soalan4, soalan5, soalan6, soalan7 ,nota) VALUES ('$soalan1','$soalan2','$soalan3','$soalan4','$soalan5','$soalan6','$soalan7','$nota')", $conn)
     or die ("Tidak boleh mencapai masuk queri.");

     echo "<center>";
     echo "<font size=5 face=Lucida Grande>";
     echo "<b>TAHNIAH!</b>";
     echo "<br/>";
     echo "Borang Survay anda telah berjaya dihantar . Terima Kasih atas kerjasama yang diberikan";
     echo "<br/>";
     echo "<br/>";
     echo "<button style=height:50px width:20px value=Kembali onClick=location.href='borang_kepuasan.php'>";
     echo "Kembali";
     echo "</button>";
     echo "</font>";
     echo "</center>";
  }
}
else
{
  ?>

<div class="container">

  <section class="content_area">
  <div class="content">



 <center><br/>
  <p><b><font size="+3" face="verdana">Borang Survay Kepuasan Pelanggan</font></b></p>


  <p>Sila tandakan nombor yang sepadan dengan tahap persetujuan anda. </p> 
  <table>
  <tr>
      <td class="td1">1 </td>
      <td> Amat Tidak Setuju </td>
      <td class="td1"> 2 </td>
      <td> Tidak Setuju  </td>
      <td class="td1"> 3 </td>
      <td> Kurang Setuju  </td>
      <td class="td1"> 4 </td>
      <td> Setuju </td>
      <td class="td1"> 5 </td>
      <td> Sangat Setuju </td>
   </tr> 
 </table> 

 <hr>
  <form name="form1" method="post" action=""><br/>
 <table class="table1">
  <tr>
    <th>Bil</th>
    <th>Perkara</th>
    <th>1</th>
    <th>2</th>
    <th>3</th>
    <th>4</th>
    <th>5</th>
  </tr>

  <tr>
      <td>1 </td>
      <td> Akaun Instagram & Facebook Dweet sangat berinformasi & membantu saya. </td>
      <td> <input type="radio" name="soalan1" value="Amat tak setuju " >  </td>
      <td> <input type="radio" name="soalan1" value="Tidak setuju " >  </td>
      <td> <input type="radio" name="soalan1" value="Kurang setuju " >  </td>
      <td> <input type="radio" name="soalan1" value="Setuju " >  </td>
      <td> <input type="radio" name="soalan1" value="Sangat setuju " >  </td>
   </tr> 

    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td> Saya rasa team Dweet menghargai saya sebagai pelanggan.  </td>
      <td> <input type="radio" name="soalan2" value="Amat tak setuju " >  </td>
      <td> <input type="radio" name="soalan2" value="Tidak setuju " >  </td>
      <td> <input type="radio" name="soalan2" value="Kurang setuju " >  </td>
      <td> <input type="radio" name="soalan2" value="Setuju " >  </td>
      <td> <input type="radio" name="soalan2" value="Sangat setuju " >  </td>
   </tr> 

  <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td> Saya tidak mengalami masalah ketika dalam proses pesanan.  </td>
      <td> <input type="radio" name="soalan3" value="Amat tak setuju " >  </td>
      <td> <input type="radio" name="soalan3" value="Tidak setuju " >  </td>
      <td> <input type="radio" name="soalan3" value="Kurang setuju " >  </td>
      <td> <input type="radio" name="soalan3" value="Setuju " >  </td>
      <td> <input type="radio" name="soalan3" value="Sangat setuju " >  </td>
   </tr> 

 <tr>
      <td>4</td>
      <td> Tempahan saya siap pada hari yang dijanjikan.  </td>
      <td> <input type="radio" name="soalan4" value="Amat tak setuju " >  </td>
      <td> <input type="radio" name="soalan4" value="Tidak setuju " >  </td>
      <td> <input type="radio" name="soalan4" value="Kurang setuju " >  </td>
      <td> <input type="radio" name="soalan4" value="Setuju " >  </td>
      <td> <input type="radio" name="soalan4" value="Sangat setuju " >  </td>
   </tr> 

   <tr>
      <td>5</td>
      <td> Pesanan saya siap seperti yang telah saya tempah.  </td>
      <td> <input type="radio" name="soalan5" value="Amat tak setuju " >  </td>
      <td> <input type="radio" name="soalan5" value="Tidak setuju " >  </td>
      <td> <input type="radio" name="soalan5" value="Kurang setuju " >  </td>
      <td> <input type="radio" name="soalan5" value="Setuju " >  </td>
      <td> <input type="radio" name="soalan5" value="Sangat setuju " >  </td>
   </tr> 

   <tr>
      <td>6</td>
      <td> Saya akan mengesyorkan Dweet kepada rakan-rakan dan ahli keluarga saya.  </td>
      <td> <input type="radio" name="soalan6" value="Amat tak setuju " >  </td>
      <td> <input type="radio" name="soalan6" value="Tidak setuju " >  </td>
      <td> <input type="radio" name="soalan6" value="Kurang setuju " >  </td>
      <td> <input type="radio" name="soalan6" value="Setuju " >  </td>
      <td> <input type="radio" name="soalan6" value="Sangat setuju " >  </td>
   </tr> 

 <tr>
      <td>7</td>
      <td> Secara keseluruhan,saya sangat berpuas hati menjadi pelanggan Dweet.  </td>
      <td> <input type="radio" name="soalan7" value="Amat tak setuju " >  </td>
      <td> <input type="radio" name="soalan7" value="Tidak setuju " >  </td>
      <td> <input type="radio" name="soalan7" value="Kurang setuju " >  </td>
      <td> <input type="radio" name="soalan7" value="Setuju " >  </td>
      <td> <input type="radio" name="soalan7" value="Sangat setuju " >  </td>
   </tr> 

</table>
      <p> Nota / Testimoni <br/>
      <textarea name="nota" rows="7" cols="70" > </textarea>
      </p>





            <p>&nbsp;</p>
                <button type="button" value="Laman Utama" onClick="location.href='index.html'" >Laman Utama </button>
                <button type="submit" name="hantar" value="Hantar Borang">Hantar Borang</button>


<p><h3>Terima Kasih</h3>
Kerana meluangkan sedikit masa menjawab soalan survey ini. <br/>
Ianya sangat membantu kami untuk membaiki lagi servis syarikat.<br/>
Anda sangat Ohsem!</p>

       </center>

 </section>
 </form>
 <br/>
 <div id="footer">
    <center><p><b>DWEET CARD</b><br/><font size="2">56-1,Jalan 8/36, Seri Bangi,Seksyen 8, 43650 Bandar Baru Bangi, Selangor<br/>Tel: +603 8912 3812   Whatsapp: +6017 3424341   Laman Web: www.thinkd.com.my</font></p> 
    <br/><br/></div>
    </center>
 </div>
  <?php
}
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mysql_query can return boolean false if sql error happens

```
    if($result === false) {
        var_dump(mysql_error());
    }
    else {
        if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
            if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
                while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                    echo "<tr>";
                    echo "<td>$row[soalan1]</td>";
                    echo "<td>$row[soalan2]</td>";
                    echo "<td>$row[soalan3]</td>";
                    echo "<td>$row[soalan4]</td>";
                    echo "<td>$row[soalan5]</td>";
                    echo "<td>$row[soalan6]</td>";
                    echo "<td>$row[soalan7]</td>";
                    echo "<td>$row[nota]</td>";
                    echo "</tr>";
                }
            } else {
                echo "0 results";
            }
        }
    }
```

Also you can just change the line

```
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
```

to:

```
if ($result !== false && mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
```

But you'll need to var_dump the mysql error to see what went wrong with your query

P.S. This was answered million times

Comment: where should i put that? sorry i'm not good in this php subject.

Comment: I've edited the unswer. You should replace your if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) { with it's content with the code I gave you.

Comment: thanks a lot. there are no warning anymore but something come out at my page  " bool(false)"

Comment: what happens if your run "SELECT * FROM borang_kepuasan" in you phpadmin or whatever you are using for accessing the database.
There is an error somewhere, may be in your query and you don't have any results.

Comment: When i run the borang_kepuasan its come out this : Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, string given in /home/dweetcom/public_html/borang_kepuasan.php on line 153

Comment: i have put the borang_kepuasan.php form that i create